# Convert excel file with Multiple sheets to single JSON format in pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have an excel file that looks like this:
[Sheet1 of my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyCID.png),
[Sheet2 of my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gd93.png)

Ideally inorder to convert this data into my required JSON using Pandas I would do this:

```
appfile = pd.read_excel('AppTest.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
appfile.to_json(path_or_buf = 'AppTest_json.json', orient = 'records', lines = True)
```

now, output for this is something like this:

```
{"app_id_c":116092749,"cust_id_n":95014843,"laa_app_appr_term_n":36,"laa_promotionscheme":504627,"laa_branchid":8,"laa_app_type_c":"C"}
{"app_id_c":116189540,"cust_id_n":95117032,"laa_app_appr_term_n":48,"laa_promotionscheme":512932,"laa_branchid":48,"laa_app_type_c":"C"}
{"app_id_c":116157227,"cust_id_n":95082957,"laa_app_appr_term_n":36,"laa_promotionscheme":512573,"laa_branchid":136,"laa_app_type_c":"C"}
```

but the output that I need, needs data from the second sheet as well, so JSON for one row of data should look something like this:

```
{
"app_id_c":116092749,
"cust_id_n":95014843,
"laa_app_appr_term_n":36,
"laa_promotionscheme":504627,
"laa_branchid":8,
"laa_app_type_c":"C",
"LOS_INPUT_FROMSAS": [
  {
   "lsi_app_id_c":116092749,
   "lsi_cust_type_c":"G"
  }
 ]
}
```

How to get this kind of JSON that will consolidate my other sheet too?

Answer (score 2):

You can read all of your sheets as a dictionary of dataframes by doing:

```
appfile = pd.read_excel('AppTest.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

This will make appfile a dict structured {sheet_name: Dataframe}, and you can loop through that dictionary and do whatever you like with each sheet. It seems like you have a good understanding of writing to json already, so I will leave it up to you to write the json however you like.

Best of luck!